# How to fetch more than 1000 bans of a discord server using discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a command `serverinfo` and it shows how many bans there are on the server. If the server has 1200 bans, the bot will show that the server has 1000 bans.

**Is it possible to somehow make the bot shows how many bans really are?**

In the [documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild-bans) the following parameters are specified `limit?| number | number of users to return (up to maximum 1000) | default 1000`

**How to change default 1000 to e.g. 1500?**

I am using discord.js vers 13.8.0 and node.js version 16.15.1.

Comment: could you please provide a code you are using for it right now?

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft I've always used `message.guild.bans.fetch()` so I only have that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a v13 discord.js solution to your problem, this is what I did.

I edited this to include the while loop.

```
let completeBanIdList = await (async (a = [], last = 0, limit = 1000) => {
    while(limit === 1000){
        let bans = await guild.bans.fetch({after: last, limit: limit});
        let banlist = bans.map(user => user.user.id);
        
        last = bans.last().user.id;
        limit = banlist.length;
            
        for(let i = 0; i < limit; i++){a.push(banlist[i]);}
    }

    return a;
})();




// below is just console logging to show that it worked properly...

let banIdObj = ((o = {}) => {
    for(let i = 0; i < completeBanIdList.length; i++){
        o[completeBanIdList[i]] = 1;
    }
    
    return o;
})();

console.log(`unique ban id count:`, completeBanIdList.length, `should equal number of id keys in object:`, Object.keys(banIdObj).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the max limit is 1000, you can use the [`limit` and `before` options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/FetchBansOptions) to fetch the previous bans, too. `before` is a snowflake, it tells Discord to consider only bans before this id.

So, if you have around 1200 bans, you can fetch the first 1000, grab the id of the last item in the returned collection and use its `id` as the `before` option in your second fetch:

```js
let firstHalf = await guild.bans.fetch({ limit: 1000 });
let secondHalf = await guild.bans.fetch({ before: firstHalf.last().id, limit: 1000 });
```

You can also create a new function that fetches more than 1000 bans. There is an example below. This function returns a `collection` of [`GuildBan`s](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildBan), so you can use the usual [collection methods](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/main/class/Collection), like `filter`, `each`, etc.

```js
async function fetchMoreBans(guild, limit = 2000) {
  if (!guild || typeof guild !== 'object')
    throw new Error(`Expected a guild, got "${typeof guild}"`);
  if (!Number.isInteger(limit))
    throw new Error(`Expected an integer, got ${typeof limit}.`);
  if (limit <= 1000) return guild.bans.fetch({ limit });

  let collection = new Collection();
  let lastId = null;
  let options = {};
  let remaining = limit;

  while (remaining > 0) {
    options.limit = remaining > 1000 ? 1000 : remaining;
    remaining = remaining > 1000 ? remaining - 1000 : 0;

    if (lastId) options.before = lastId;

    let bans = await guild.bans.fetch(options);

    if (!bans.last()) break;

    collection = collection.concat(bans);
    lastId = bans.last().id;
  }

  return collection;
}
```

Example usage:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  let banList = await fetchMore(message.guild, 1500);
  let filteredBanList = banList.filter(({ user }) =>
    user.username.toLowerCase().startsWith('e'),
  );

  console.log(`There are ${banList.size} bans fetched`);
  console.log(
    `Number of bans where the user's username starts with the letter "e": ${filteredBanList.size}`,
  );
});
```

Comment: It doesn't work, in the first one it shows 1000 and 1000 and in the second only 1000
Server has 1004 bans